# Show array data in HTML table multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array like this:-

```
$str = array(
    array(
        'amount' => 1.87,
        'user' => 'hello',
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 0.9,
        'user' => 'test',
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 9,
        'user' => 'hello',
    ),
    array(
        'amount' => 1.4,
        'user' => 'test',
    )
);
```

Now I show this data in HTML table like this for user 'test' :-

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>User</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php
            foreach ($str as $new_str) {
                if ($new_str['user'] == "test") {
                    echo $new_str['amount'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }

            ?></td><td><?php
            foreach ($str as $new_str) {
                if ($new_str['user'] == "test") {
                    echo $new_str['user'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
            ?></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

But now the problem is that when I use this code it shows the amount and user as a whole instead of two different rows. How can I fix this? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to move your `foreach` loop outside of the `<tr>...</tr>` structure. This should work:

```
<?php foreach($str as $new_str){
    if($new_str['user']=="test"){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $new_str['amount'] . "</td><td>" . $new_str['user'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
?>
```

Output (for your data)

```
<tr><td>0.9</td><td>test</td></tr>
<tr><td>1.4</td><td>test</td></tr>
```

Comment: Rats!  You beat me by seconds!  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your tr was not repeating. [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjNe7.png) I hope this will help.

```
    <?php
       $str = array(
            array(
                'amount' => 1.87,
                'user' => 'hello',
            ),
            array(
                'amount' => 0.9,
                'user' => 'test' ,
            ),
            array(
                'amount' => 9,
                'user' => 'hello',
            ),
            array(
                'amount' => 1.4,
                'user' => 'test',
            )
);
?>
<table>
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
                <?php foreach($str as $new_str) {
                    if($new_str['user'] == "test"){
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'.$new_str['amount'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$new_str['user'].'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```